# In WatchKit can't access UserDefaults

Tags: swift, watchkit

I add as a new target WatchKit and I need use in watch UserDefaults and I added both targets into single AppGroup but I can't get values from UserDefaults from WatchKit when I debug `UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.my.app")` like this it gives me value of UserDefaults and when I get value from UserDefaults it didn't gives me in Watch app but in iOS app it gives me value

`UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.my.app")?.bool(forKey: "dark_mode")` when I use this code it gives me true but in watch app it gives false in fact it should be true

Get values from Watch app in UserDefaults

Comment: It would likely be best if you reword your question it is contradicting itself. Some code might help.

Comment: As explained in the linked Q&A, Apple Watch apps don't have access to the AppGroup of iOS apps. You cannot share UserDefaults between an Apple Watch and iOS app without implementing the synchronisation yourself through some other solution (such as WatchConnectivity or iCloud for instance).

Comment: It is important to understand that app group sharing, whether keychain or user defaults or files, only works between different targets/apps on a single device. So you can share between your main app and an extension or another app you make on a single iPhone, but that data is not shared to another device the user might have, whether a watch or an iPad. The same in the watch. Data is shared between your main watch target & a widget extension. To share between the phone and a paired watch, use a [watch connectivity session](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity/wcsession).